# ConcurrentModificationException from Firebase

Tags: java, android, concurrentmodification

I keep getting this ConcurrentModificationException from Firebase

```
Exception java.util.ConcurrentModificationException:
java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next (ArrayList.java:573)
```

I'm running out of ideas how to fix this. I already tried so many changes in the code. The exception happens on this line, according to Firebase:

```
for (Show show : entityListLanguages) { }
```

I already changed the code multiple times (such as using "addAll" outside of the loop etc.) but I still get the bug. Now I'm out of ideas what I could change to fix this.

Here is my current code:

```
List<Show> entityListLanguages = movieTheatreShowtimesListItemRecyclerViewAdapter.getShowList(); // This just returns a list, no special thread of background process

movieLanguageList = new ArrayList<>();                               
availableLanguages.clear();                                          
for (Show show : entityListLanguages) {                              
    MovieLanguage movieLanguage = new MovieLanguage();               
    movieLanguage.setId(show.getSpokenLanguage());                   
    movieLanguage.setName(show.getSpokenLanguageFormatted());        
    if (!movieLanguageList.contains(movieLanguage)) {                
        movieLanguage.setMovieCount(1);                              
        movieLanguageList.add(movieLanguage);                        
    }                                                                
}                                                                    
availableLanguages.addAll(movieLanguageList);
```

The only line I can imagine that might cause a problem would be:

```
movieLanguageList.add(movieLanguage);
```

but then again I don't know how else I could solve this.

Am I missing something? Thanks for any hints.

Complete stack trace:

```
java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next (ArrayList.java:573)
ch.cineman.ShowtimesFragmentHelper.updateAvailableLanguages (ShowtimesFragmentHelper.java:381)
ch.cineman.ShowtimesFragmentHelper.updateAvailableGenres (ShowtimesFragmentHelper.java:370)
ch.cineman.ShowtimesByMovieFragment$6$1.onListViewUpdated (ShowtimesByMovieFragment.java:301)
ch.cineman.MovieTheatreShowtimesListItemRecyclerViewAdapter$4$3.run (MovieTheatreShowtimesListItemRecyclerViewAdapter.java:569)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7224)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

And the more extended code snippet:

**Note: entityListLanguages and entityListGenres aren't modified anywhere else in the code.**

```
private List<Show> entityListGenres;
private List<Show> entityListLanguages;
protected MovieTheatreShowtimesListItemRecyclerViewAdapter movieTheatreShowtimesListItemRecyclerViewAdapter;


    /**
     * Helper method
     */
    protected void updateAvailableGenres() {
        entityListGenres = movieTheatreShowtimesListItemRecyclerViewAdapter.getShowList();

        listedMovies = new ArrayList<>();
        movieGenreList = new ArrayList<>();
        availableGenres.clear();

        for (Show show : entityListGenres) {
            Movie movieX = show.getMovie();
            if (movieX != null) {
                if (!listedMovies.contains(movieX)) {
                    listedMovies.add(movieX);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Movie listedMovie : listedMovies) {
            if (listedMovie.getGenres() != null && listedMovie.getGenres().size() > 0) {
                for (MovieGenre movieGenre : listedMovie.getGenres()) {
                    if (!movieGenreList.contains(movieGenre)) {
                        movieGenre.setMovieCount(1);
                        movieGenreList.add(movieGenre);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        availableGenres.addAll(movieGenreList);
        CinemanApplication.getCurrentAppInstance().setAvailableGenres(availableGenres);

        updateAvailableLanguages();
    }

    /**
     * Helper method
     */
    protected void updateAvailableLanguages() {
        entityListLanguages = movieTheatreShowtimesListItemRecyclerViewAdapter.getShowList();

        movieLanguageList = new ArrayList<>();
        availableLanguages.clear();
        for (Show show : entityListLanguages) {
            MovieLanguage movieLanguage = new MovieLanguage();
            movieLanguage.setId(show.getSpokenLanguage());
            movieLanguage.setName(show.getSpokenLanguageFormatted());
            if (!movieLanguageList.contains(movieLanguage)) {
                movieLanguage.setMovieCount(1);
                movieLanguageList.add(movieLanguage);
            }
        }
        availableLanguages.addAll(movieLanguageList);
        CinemanApplication.getCurrentAppInstance().setAvailableLanguages(availableLanguages);
    }
```

getShowList() is in the "movieTheatreShowtimesListItemRecyclerViewAdapter" class and looks like this:

```
List<Show> getShowList() {
    return showList;
}
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: Is `entityListLanguages` being modified in another thread?

Comment: How is `availableLanguages` defined / where does it come from?

Comment: You still did not tell us in which line the error occurs.

Comment: According to the bug report the exception happens in this line: for (Show show : entityListLanguages) {

Comment: instead of the `add if not contains` logic you can use  a `Set` instead that would do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue most like be the adding of the new content to the list. A common `for(Type obj : list)` loop uses the common `Iterator` provided by the `Iterable` interface. However modifing the list **during iteration** throws the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

**Faulty code ( Throws ConcurrentModificationException ):**

```
List<Integer> li = new Random().ints(10000,0,10).boxed().collect( Collectors.toList() );

for(Integer i : li)
{
  if(i.intValue() == 5)
  {
    li.add( Integer.valueOf( 2 ) );
  }
}
```

To prevent this you can use the `ListIterator` which is enforced by the `List` interface.

**Working code:**

```
List<Integer> li = new Random().ints(10000,0,10).boxed().collect( Collectors.toList() );

for(ListIterator<Integer> it = li.listIterator();it.hasNext();)
{
  if(it.next().intValue() == 5)
  {
    it.add( Integer.valueOf( 2 ) );
  }
}
```

---

Note: This is just an example using Integers since I have no access to OPs type of objects.

Comment: I'm not adding anything to a list I'm currently iterating through. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @e-nature my bad mixed up the lists. However the concrete cause for the exception mostly likely be that the _expected_ count of objects differs from the _actual_ count within the list.

Answer (score -1):

**To Avoid ConcurrentModificationException in multi-threaded environment:**

1. You can convert the list to an array and then iterate on the array. This approach works well for small or medium size list but if the list is large then it will affect the performance a lot.
2. You can lock the list while iterating by putting it in a synchronized block. This approach is not recommended because it will cease the benefits of multithreading.
3. If you are using JDK1.5 or higher then you can use ConcurrentHashMap and CopyOnWriteArrayList classes. It is the recommended approach.

**To Avoid ConcurrentModificationException in single-threaded environment:**

You can use the iterator remove() function to remove the object from underlying collection object. But in this case you can remove the same object and not any other object from the list.